# Extract rules in the randomForest model

Tags: r

I have created a random forest model for classification. The memory size of the model is too large. I want to use this random forest model to predict class labels for new observations. How can I extract only the rules associated with each tree to save the memory size. A similar question is asked before in here 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102667/reduce-random-forest-model-memory-size.

Comment: Have a look at inTrees package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inTrees/inTrees.pdf)

Comment: Hi @Cybernetic, if you don't mind me asking: can inTrees be used with randomForest or just with the RRF? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GoldmanClarck Yes, I believe so. See halfway down the page here: https://sites.google.com/site/houtaodeng/intrees